# Extract a buffer having different types of data with it

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

Can a buffer have both string and image associated with it? If so, how to extract them separately.

An example case would be a buffer with image data and also file name data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked with sharedArrayBuffers/arrayBuffers before.

If you are storing image pixel data, it's going to be a u32-int array, with 4 8-bit segment controlling rbga respectively... yes: you CAN tack on string data at the front in the form of a 'header' if you encode it and decode it to int values... but I have a hard time understanding why that might be desirable. because working with raw pixel data that is ONLY pixel-data is simpler. (I usually just stick it as a property of an object, with whatever other data I want to store)

Comment: also note. jpeg and other compressed image formats... that IS what they do (a header to determine the file type.

Answer (score 0):

## Data Buffers

### Typed arrays

You can use [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) to create a buffer to hold the data. You then create a view using a [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray). eg unsigned characters [Uint8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array). Types can be 8-16-32-64 bit (un/signed integers), float - double  (32 - 64 bit floating point)

One buffer can have many view. You can read and write to view just like any JS array. The values are automatically converted to the correct type when you write to a buffer, and converted to `Number` when you read from a view

#### Example

Using buffer and views to read different data types

For example say you have file data that has a 4 character header, followed by a 16 bit unsigned integer chunk length, then 2 signed 16 bit integer coordinates, and more data

```
const fileBuffer = ArrayBuffer(fileSizeInBytes);

// Create a view of the buffer so we can fill it with file data
const dataRaw = new Uint8Array(data);
// load the data into dataRaw 

// To get a string from the data we can create a util function
function readBufferString(buffer, start, length) {

    // create a view at the position of the string in the buffer
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer, start, length);

    // read each byte converting to JS unicode string
    var str = "", idx = 0;
    while (idx < length) { str += String.fromCharCode(bytes[idx++]) }
    return str;
}

// get 4 char chunk header at start of buffer    
const header = readBufferString(fileBuffer, 0, 4);
if (header === "HEAD") {
    // Create views for 16 bit signed and unsigned integers
    const ints = new Int16Array(fileBuffer);
    const uints = new Uint16Array(fileBuffer);
    const length = uints[2]; // get the length as unsigned int16
    const x = ints[3]; // get the x coord as signed int16
    const y = ints[4]; // get the y coord as signed int16
```

### A [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView)

The above example is one way of extracting the different types of data from a single buffer. However there could be an problem with older files and some data sources regarding the order of bytes that create multi byte types (eg 32 integers). This is called [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

To help with using the correct endianness and to simplify access to all the different data types in a buffer you can use a [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView)

The data view lets you read from the buffer by type and endianness. For example to read a unsigned 64bit integer from a buffer

```
 // fileBuffer is a array buffer with the data
 // Create a view
 const dataView = new DataView(fileBuffer);
 
 // read the 64 bit uint starting at the first byte in the buffer
 // Note the returned value is a BigInt not a Number
 const bInt = dataView.getBigUint64(0);

 // If the int was in little endian order you would use
 const bInt = dataView.getBigUint64(0, true); // true for little E
```

### Notes

- Buffers are not dynamic. That means they can not grow and shrink and that you must know how large the buffer needs to be when you create it.
- Buffers tend to be a little slower than JavaScript's standard array as there is a lot type coercion when read or writing to buffers
- Buffers can be transferred (Zero copy transfer) across threads making them ideal for distributing large data structures between WebWorkers. There is also a SharedArrayBuffer that lets you create true parallel processing solutions in JS